# Grunt not defined

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am new to Grunt and have been struggling all day to make this work:
**This is my Gulpfile.js**:

```
'use strict';

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Automatically load required Grunt tasks
require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },

            all: {
                src: [
                    'Gruntfile.js',
                    'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'jshint'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
};
```

**This my package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "conFusion",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.10.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.2.1",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

**And this is the error message i get**:

> grunt build
>
> Loading "Gruntfile.js"
>
> tasks...ERROR >>
>       ReferenceError: grunt is not defined
>
> Warning: Task "build" not found.Use--force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Pls guys, I need help. I am working on windows 10, so am using the command line there.

Comment: You are using GRUNT and not GULP

Comment: You probably need to install grunt first

Comment: `grunt` is passed as argument to the exported function but you are trying to access it *outside* of that function. Move the `require` calls inside the function. This has nothing to do with `grunt` specifically, but with *variable scope* in JavaScript. You might want to take a look at [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/218196)

Comment: Thanks, it worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  module.exports = function(grunt) {
> ```

That is where you define a `grunt` variable. It is an argument to the function you created.

But you try to use it here:

> ```
>  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
> ```

and here:

> ```
>  require('jit-grunt')(grunt);
> ```

This is **outside** the function where the variable does not exist.

Move those lines **inside** the function.